# 4 month old puppy RAN from crate to her bed in the living to pee on it after peeing outside just an hour ago. Always likes to pee on her bed. Why?

Tags: dogs

I have a 4 month old puppy mongrel who is well train, very, VERY well exercised (but not over the top), command trained, space confinement / crate trained, taken out about 4 or 5 times a day to pee / poo.

She has a crate and 2 very comfy beds (exact same model) which I bought for her.

She LOVES to pee on her bed (and she really loves her bed as well it's super comfy), has happened many times before. I can't understand why and I'm thinking maybe she wants to "claim" the bed as hers but in that case shouldn't she just mark it with a little pee not the whole flow? And this also goes against the principle that dogs like to keep their sleeping area clean.

As such I have taken away the beds and only put it out beside me (so that I can supervise) for her to lie on it only after she has peed outside.

However just 15min ago she RAN from crate to her bed just outside the crate to pee on it after peeing outside just an hour ago. Always likes to pee on her bed. Why?

Can someone help me understand her psychology / what's going on in her mind? thanks so Much! I love my Puppy!

P.S. when she sleeps for the night in her crate and needs to pee, she diligently goes to the pee tray in her cage to pee in it which is great, I just don't understand why she wants to pee on her comfy bed

Comment: She only does it on one of her bed? Where is that bed located? Also: Can you tell me how is a day in the life of your dog? Is there areas she is forbidden to go inside the house and where family members spend a lot of time? Do you monitor the meal/bed/outside times and even free time of your dog? Does your dog eat her food in that bed or doesn't eat food at the bowl? Also, why the "very VERY well exercised"? Do you have some kind of strict training with the dog?

Answer (score 3):

There is not telling what's actually in her mind, but I have two thoughts for you. One is the smell. You have to use a special cleaner to get all the pee smell out. If you don't, then her natural instinct is to go in the same spot as the smell fades to "remark" her territory.

Another theory is that she associates that type of bed with a place to go to the bathroom. I'd try to remove those styles of beds and buy one that's different and see what happens. She might just associate faux wool pillow beds with peeing. I'd try a cloth one with sides. You get the idea. Change the location of the bed, the style of bed, and get a pet urine cleaner for accidents.

Once she understands that she shouldn't be peeing on bedding, then you can probably use it again.

Comment: Additionally, sometimes a thing becomes too soiled to simply be washed out (especially in cases where urine/feces sit undiscovered), and you will discover no matter what you do, the dog always goes there. In these cases the soiled object must be tossed. A doggie bed is easy to replace - carpet, not so much.

Comment: That's true. My grandmother's dog ruined her hardwood floors, pretty much permanently. The pee also went through the carpet and soaked into the foam mat underneath. If the dog can't be trusted no matter what, then another option is to keep it on a long leash whenever it's out of the crate till it can be trusted. I've read where trainers say that some can never be fully trusted. I think your issue will resolve in time. Remember, you can't expect perfection from a puppy who doesn't have full bladder control. This issue isn't about her bladder control, but it still applies when I say be patient.